# Need to add user confirmation and a running total to simple ticketing system

Tags: java, netbeans

I've got to complete a current assignment that I've been making some changes to and I am stuck on what I hope will be my last problem before submission

I need to create a simple ticketing system for a cinema, and I have been able to create (with the help of other experienced developers) a working system. However, the ticketing system needs to prompt the user for confirmation to continue the method, and to show a current total cost. The confirmation needs to be the user entering the number 1, if not, to output an error message.

I've attempted using the `again = br.readLine();` to output the 1 to confirm the purchase, I have also tried importing the `java.util.Scanner` class to then input and use `int` to create an error message but it continues to show errors.

```
 package ticketingsystem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ticketingsystem {

    enum TicketType {
// I chose to use the enum class for the ticket prices, //
// as it made it much easier to use a switch statement, instead of multiple if statements. //        
        CHILD(18), ADULT(36), SENIOR(32.5);
//Enum classes are needed to be used in upper case, otherwise the program will crash//
//as I discovered//        
        TicketType(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        private double price;

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //As the program needed the ability to run in an indefinite loop constantly adding //
        //calculations, I chose to use buffered reader, as it buffered the method each loop//
        //continuing to add a total number.//

        String type, again;
        int quantity = 0;
        // This is where the new calculation starts, it is set at 0 before being calculated and
        //added to the total price.//
        double totalPrice = 0;
        TicketType ticketType;
        //We link the TicketType calculations to the enum class, hence//
        // TicketType ticketType.//

        System.out.println("Welcome to the cinemas!");

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU\n");
        System.out.println("Cinema has the following ticketing options\n");
        System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 yrs)");
        System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ yrs)");
        System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)");

        do {
            //Our loop calculation method starts here//
            System.out.print("\nEnter your option: ");

            type = br.readLine();

            switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
                case "1":
                    ticketType = TicketType.CHILD;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    ticketType = TicketType.ADULT;
                    break;

                default:
                    ticketType = TicketType.SENIOR;
                    break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter total No of tickets: ");

            quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity;
            //totalPrice is the ticketType cost (hence the += operator), times//
            //the quantity.//
            System.out.printf("--> You are purchasing %s - %s Ticket(s) at $%s\n", quantity, ticketType, ticketType.getPrice());
            System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm purchase");

            //This is where we confirm the purchase//
            // This is where the current total cost needs to be output //
            System.out.print("\nDo you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : ");

            again = br.readLine();

        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        //This is where the calculation method ends (as we are using a do/while loop).//
        // The while statement means that if we type "y", the loop will begin again with a buffer.//
        //If we type N, the loop will end, and the program will continue running past the loop.//
        System.out.printf("\n==> Total Price : $%s \n", totalPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: *but it continues to show errors* - what are they?

Comment: I tried this for the current total cost
System.out.print("Press 1 to confirm purchase");
System.out.printf("\n==>$%s \n"); and there was a sym error

Comment: I ran your code and got no error, except that you don't have anything regarding pressing 1 to accept purchase. It just accepts purchases all the time. Is that your issue?

Comment: Almost.. There are a few additions I need to make to the program and I'm stumped on how best to write into the existing method..

- When you press 1 to continue, the method continues output
- Output shows what current total ticket cost is
- If user does not press 1, error message appears and loop resets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to have to press `1` to accept purchase, then just put in a simple `if...else` after asking that question. Something like:

```
String confirmation = br.readLine();
if (confirmation.equals("1")) {
    totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity;
    System.out.println("Current total is: " + totalPrice);
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not press 1 so ticket purchase cancelled");
    System.out.println("Current cost is still: " + totalPrice);
}
```

So this way it will only update the total if they press `1`.

[**Example**](https://ideone.com/BUQj5Q)

Comment: Ah legend thanks! I had tried using an if statement, but I had not tried string confirmation. That's solved my problem, thank you very much :)